# What commands should I send to Tasmota (DHT11) via MQTT Broker to receive status as message in my NodeJS script?

Tags: mqtt, tasmota, nodejs

I cannot find how to send command to my Tasmota DHT11 device via MQTT Broker.

I'm using mqtt.js library in Nodejs.

```js
var mqtt = require('mqtt');
var topic = 'cmnd/tasmota_E30D62/';
var client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://localhost:1883');

client.on('connect', function(){

    //subscription to topic
    client.subscribe(topic, function(){
        client.on('message', function(topic, message, packet){
            console.log('Received ' + message + ' on topic ' + topic);
        });
    });

    //publish a message to topic
    client.publish(topic, '', function(){
        console.log('message is published');
        client.end();
    })
})
```

I can see that the message is going to my MQTT broker, and then send to the right topic. I can see that in the Tasmota Console.

In the Tasmota Console, if I run 'Status 10', I got the data I'm targeting. When I run my NodeJS script including the same message, I got the log :

```
MQT: stat/tasmota_E30D62/RESULT = {"Command":"Unknown"}
```

So what message, should I send to get the data from my Tasmota sensor as an answer in my NodeJS ?

Comment: Please do not cross post the same question to multiple Stack Exchange sites https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68873557/what-commands-should-i-send-to-tasmota-dht11-via-mqtt-broker-to-receive-status

Comment: It appears that one does not send commands to the Tasmota sensor. Only get responses. One configures it via yaml. See https://community.home-assistant.io/t/no-data-from-tasmota-via-mqtt/102574/4 for an example of how someone else made it work.